# Custom style for markers in ace editor

Tags: css, ace-editor

Is it possible to set a custom style for an individual marker?
I'm trying to set the border color to a custom one for each marker I add, instead of using one single class. Those colors are ones I can't know in advance and I need to set them while the program is running. This is why I can't create a dozen classes and use them for this purpose.

Comment: Can you use IDs instead of classes?

Comment: What is a marker?

Comment: It was edited to say ' in ace editor' after the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic marker similar to what cloud9 uses here https://github.com/c9/core/blob/2d05ddeb7c0c1f6f3b35e305f60d1ba4f39f0294/plugins/c9.ide.collab/author_layer.js#L41 https://github.com/c9/core/blob/2d05ddeb7c0c1f6f3b35e305f60d1ba4f39f0294/plugins/c9.ide.collab/author_layer.js#L98

Answer (score -3):

Here is one way you can do that: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/wkwzprfh/

### markup

```
<ul class="marker-type-list">

  <li class='marker-type'>
    <button class='js-create-marker' data-color='red'>Create red marker</button>
  </li>

  <li class='marker-type'>
    <button class='js-create-marker' data-color='green'>Create green marker</button>
  </li>

  <li class='marker-type'>
    <button class='js-create-marker' data-color='blue'>Create blue marker</button>
  </li>

</ul>

<ul class='marker-list'><!-- X --></ul>
```

### script

```
$('.js-create-marker').on('click', function() {
    var color = $(this).data('color');
    console.log(color);
  $('.marker-list').append('<li class="marker ' + color + '">marker</li>');
});
```

### styles

```
.marker.red {
  color: red;
}

.marker.green {
  color: green;
}

.marker.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```